# Providing Dispatches.Main for runBlocking hang the Android App. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I'm running the code below in Android, it runs fine.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        runBlocking {
            launch { 
                Log.d("Track", "main runBlocking pre       : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                delay(500)
                Log.d("Track", "main runBlocking post      : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }
        }
    }
```

It print

```
Track: main runBlocking pre       : main
Track: main runBlocking post      : main
```

However, if I provide the Main context to `runBlocking`, as I have below

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) { // Provide Dispatchers.Main
            launch { 
                Log.d("Track", "main runBlocking pre       : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                delay(500)
                Log.d("Track", "main runBlocking post      : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }
        }
    }
```

it hangs and not running it.

**Note:** the `Dispatchers.Main` is using

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'
```

Why did it hang?

I thought not providing `Dispatchers.Main` to the `runBlocking` is to have it run in main thread, which is the same as providing `Dispatchers.Main`. Did I mis-understand it?

**Note:**
The libraries I use are as below

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.21"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.2'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`runBlocking`'s default dispatcher is a custom dispatcher that uses the thread it was called on to run the continuations of the coroutine. This is why when you log from within the `runBlocking` coroutine block, it reports that it is on the main thread.

However, this is different that running something on `Dispatchers.Main.` `Dispatchers.Main` literally handles coroutine continuations by posting code blocks as runnables to the main Handler. However, that handler is currently running this `onCreate` method, and won't be able to handle other messages in its queue until `onCreate` returns. But `runBlocking` won't return until its child coroutines return, so `onCreate` can never return.

The default `runBlocking` dispatcher on the other hand runs the continuations directly on the current thread before it even returns. It doesn't even know about Handlers. If you launch a coroutine into `Dispatchers.main` from within `runBlocking` with its default dispatcher, I think you'll have the same kind of hang.

Comment: Can I assume the `runBlocking` by default is not running on the `Dispatchers.Main`, although it is state to be running on the `main` thread?

Comment: Where does it say it’s running on the main thread?

Comment: If I experiment it with `runBlocking { Log.d("Track", "${Thread.currentThread()}") }`. It print out `Thread[main @coroutine#5,5,main]`

Comment: And in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html, it also mention `When launch { ... } is used without parameters, it inherits the context (and thus dispatcher) from the CoroutineScope it is being launched from. In this case, it inherits the context of the main runBlocking coroutine which runs in the main thread.`

Comment: @Elye, you're right that it's running on the main thread, but that is different than running with `Dispatchers.Main`. I revised my answer to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

I think using

```
Dispatchers.Main.immediate
```

as the parameter of the runBlocking() would work here

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-coroutine-dispatcher/immediate.html